# Text box and drop down together

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the Select, its showing up below and to right, but I need the select to hang below input and select. Or is there a custom text box with drop down menu?

I am unable to find one, so I thought about building it my self but the drop down is in wrong location, and I dont see any CSS that can help.

```html
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="Drop_Down_A" value="Select One..."><!--
    --><select id="Drop_Down_A1" style="width: 19px; height: 21px;">
    <option value="" disable>Select One...</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Got the answer I was looking for.

I have posted the new result of what I was after.

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" list="Drop_Down_A1" id="Drop_Down_A" value="Select One...">
  <datalist id="Drop_Down_A1">
    <option value="Select One..." disable>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Thank you Scott, it worked.
This feature does it have auto fill if only 1 result?

Comment: Yes, it does. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin can help you https://select2.github.io

Comment: Why not just use the HTML `datalist` element?

Comment: @ScottMarcus because your solution has not full browsers compablility. For example this code will not work in safari

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you want to achieve with this. Maybe live search? You might want to check this https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to customise the position of the dropdown in the select box.

However, there are alternatives. I think you are trying to achieve a searchable select box, so here are two solutions:

1. Use <[datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)>. Other than Safari, its support is fairly broad.
2. Using a library, such as Select2.